# How to assign the variable name to the "SET" parameter in the Update query of dbSendQuery() in R

Tags: r

I am confused in updating the columns of the table dynamically. I am having a data frame which contains the roles of the peoples in the school.

```
roles_sam <- data.frame(character(),character(),character(),character(),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(roles_sam) <- c("Student","Staff","HOD","Principal")
```

Similarly I am having another data frame which contains the start date of the roles.

```
roles_start <- data.frame(character(),character(),character(),character(),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(roles_start) <- c("Student_Start","Staff_Start","HOD_Start","Principal_Start")
```

If the role is selected as **"HOD"**, then the **"HOD_Start"** should be updated with the value given. Similarly if the role is selected as **"Staff"**, then the **"Staff_Start"** should be updated in the database.

The code I tried is:

```
a <- "HOD"
sd <- "16/01/2019"    
counter <- ncol(roles_start)
    for(i in 1:counter){
      if(names(roles_sam)[i] == a){
        role_start_date <- roles_start[i]
      }
    }
    print(role_start_date)
```

This code matches and brings the correct role_start_date for role selected. But I am not sure of how to use the **dbSendQuery()**

```
dbSendQuery(con, paste0("UPDATE table_name SET role_start_date=\'",sd,"\' ") )
```

Is this the right way? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: SQL is a relational language.  You need to tell us how to relate one row of the `roles_sam` data frame to another row in the `roles_start` data frame.  SQL generally can't just copy over values, because tables are intrinsically just unordered sets of data.

Comment: In roles_sam and roles_start I have mentioned only the column names and there are no entries in the data frame. So I am mapping the roles_sam and roles_start  and finding the column name to be updated as given by the user. So the column name to be updated in the table is obtained from the variable "role_start_date". The column obtained should be updated with the value given in "sd"

Comment: You are not understanding my comment above.  You should review the basics of SQL updates and then come back to your question later.

Answer (score 0):

You should use INSERT command with dbSendUpdate function.

```
for(i in 1:iter)){
  dbSendUpdate(jdbcConnection, "INSERT INTO TABLE NAME  VALUES(?,?,?)", YOUR_DF[i, 1], YOUR_DF[i,2], YOUR_DF[i,3]
}
```

This is one way of how to insert new values on your existing table. In the example I gave we have a table with 3 columns and we are filling it with the rows of our data frame called 'YOUR_DF'.

Comment: `dbSendUpdate` is defined in RJDBC package, and not in the "default" `DBI` (nor `odbc` nor `RSQLite`) packages. It might be sufficient to replace with `dbSendQuery`, but your SQL statement might fail if you use it against a MS SQL server with one of the fields being a primary key or other having a unique constraint.

Comment: Hello, I get an error when I use dbSendQuery with Oracle DB. This is why I suggested using dbSendUpdate. It maybe different with MS SQL

Comment: `dbSendQuery(con, paste0("UPDATE table_name SET \'",role_start_date,"\'=\'",sd,"\' ") ) ` Is something like this is possible ?

Comment: To learn how to write update queries please check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp . And please try INSERT INTO command with dbSendUpdate, it works with Oracle DB well, and might work for you too